# Can't print error message

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

When user tried to change the password and failed on it, I want to show the message from backend to the user.

With Postman, it's printing valid(?) error message with 400 Bad Request

```
{
    "old_password": [
        "Invalid password"
    ]
}
```

But here I can't print the error message here.

```
try {
    let headers = { ...};

    let response = await axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/.../`, {
      old_password: currentPassword,
      new_password1: passwordOne,
      new_password2: passwordTwo,
    }, {
      headers
    });
    if (response.status ===200) {
        dispatch({ type: CHANGE_PASSWORD_SUCCESS, payload: response.data });
    }
    callback();
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error); <- [400 error] //but I can't read this!!
    console.log('error'); 
    console.log(error.data); //undefined
    console.log(error.old_password); //undefined
    callback2(error);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`console.log(error.response.data)` worked